# How to exploit a <p> output that filters brackets but nothing else

Tags: attack-vector

(Explaining broadly as to not disclose any website information accidentally) I've found a website that has an area to input text, and that text is sent through a PUT request and output into <p> tags.

As far as I know, the request only filters angle brackets, and no other characters are filtered. Also, the <p> tags parse unicode, but don't run it.

Is there any way to exploit this? XSS doesn't seem to be an option with the bracket filter, but it seems like, since it is unfiltered, there should be some way to exploit it.

If you're wondering, the PUT request is token-protected, so I can't bypass the filter with it.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Do you mean brackets ([,]) or angle brackets (<,>)?   To confirm, you're saying that you're in an element context, meaning you are only able to write the contents of the <p> tag, and you are not able to control any of the attributes of the <p> tag (i.e. add "onmouseover='xss'"), correct?

Comment: @user52472 sorry about that. I meant angle brackets, and no, I can't control attributes to the <p> tag.

Comment: I'm not sure this one is exploitable, but give these a shot:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Is it reflected in the PUT request, or stored by the app and displayed elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any special preconditions (unusual codecs, etc.), `<p>$XSS</p>` is only vulnerable to XSS if opening angle brackets are allowed.

Without creating a tag, you can't inject content that's meaningful to your browser's HTML parser. Everything else, including fancy unicode, is just treated as plain data. However, you could make guesses about how the server prosseses the data to still achieve XSS. E.g., maybe the server converts `＜` (FULLWIDTH LESS-THAN SIGN `U+FF1C`) to an actual angle bracket on the way, or maybe `&lt;` is converted back to `<` for some odd reason - I've encountered that in the wild, but there is no indication that these tricks would work in your case.

> XSS doesn't seem to be an option with the bracket filter, but it seems like, since it is unfiltered, there should be some way to exploit it.

What other client-side vulnerabilities do you expect to encounter here? Besides XSS, keeping Unicode characters is often required for localization and doesn't cause any obvious security problems when printed in an HTML body.

That said, allowing arbitrary Unicode can be [quite annoying](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87&) (PoC: ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็&) which is why many social websites (e.g. Facebook, Twitter) limit allowed characters. Here is how it renders in Firefox:

[image]